# Dynamic variable do a null result

Tags: c#

im trying to do a dynamic variable and export the variable to another form, i watched every post for this problem but no one worked someone can help me please.

In the settings form:

```
public string javapath = "javaw.exe";
public int ram = 1024;

private void gunaTrackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "RAM:  " + gunaTrackBar1.Value + "GB";
    ram = gunaTrackBar1.Value;
}

private void gunaTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    javapath = gunaTextBox1.Text;
    Console.WriteLine(javapath);
}
```

and the main form:

```
private void gunaGradientButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Settings set = new Settings();
    Console.WriteLine(set.javapath); //where i get a null result
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Define in your words what a dynamic variable is

Comment: Your problem seems to be with the `Settings` class. Could you provide the code for that class and the details of whatever error message you get?

Comment: Also, using the word "set" is dangerous. That's a reserved word in C#.

Comment: The answer you've selected does not solve this problem. Why did you accept it?

Comment: I select it with some modification and it worked

Comment: @WolfIsHere - If it did not work as presented then you need to choose one of the following: (1) give feedback for the answerer so that they can fix the answer so it does work; (2) post your own answer that works; (3) wait for another answer that does work. We do not accept answers that don't work. It will confuse future readers if you do.

Comment: @WolfIsHere - Can you please explain your workflow? Are you displaying the `Settings` form in the `gunaGradientButton1_Click` method for the first time? Or has it already been displayed and you're trying to get back the previous form?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide value for `javapath` field from `set` object. So your code should be something like this

```
private void gunaGradientButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Settings set = new Settings();
    //this.javapath is private variable from top of the class
    set.javapath = this.javapath;
    Console.WriteLine(set.javapath);
}
```

Also highly reccomend you to see [C# naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#naming-conventions)

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The OP clearly said what code was on what form. `javapath` is part of the `Settings` form, and not "from top of the class".

Comment: As I understood there are 2 variables called "javapath", one declared in "Settings" class and second declared in that class which OP gave us.

Comment: I can't see that in the OP's question. There's only one `javapath` and that's in the `Settings` form.